# Type has no call signatures, why so difficult filter object in TypeScipt?

Tags: typescript

Have following types:

```js
export type BuyTicketData = {
  invoiceItems?: InvoiceItems;
};

export type InvoiceItems = {
  [invoiceItemId: string]: InvoiceItemData;
};
```

I try filter here:

```
const invoiceItems =  props.buyTicketData?.invoiceItems?.filter(
    ([key, value]: [key: any, value: any]) =>
      value.max == undefined || value.defaultValue === undefined || value.defaultValue == 1,
  )
```

but get an error:

```
./components/product/InvoiceItemsToDeliver.tsx:12:60
Type error: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'InvoiceItemData' has no call signatures.

  10 | const InvoiceItemsToDeliver = (props: ProductProps) => {
  11 | 
> 12 |   const invoiceItems =  props.buyTicketData?.invoiceItems?.filter(
     |                                                            ^
  13 |       ([key, value]: [key: any, value: any]) =>
  14 |         value.max == undefined || value.defaultValue === undefined || value.defaultValue == 1,
  15 |     )
```

What is wrong? Shall I use a flatmap?

Comment: Are you expecting InvoiceItems to actually be an _array_? Because that's **not** what your definitions say. And we can't actually see what an InvoiceItemData is, but evidently it's not callable - why did you expect otherwise?

Comment: nono, it is an 'object', it has key-value content: `[key, value]`

Comment: OK, so why exactly do you think it has a filter method? _Is_ InvoiceItemData, which is what that resolves to, supposed to be callable? If not, _why are you calling it_? And if so, it seems the type (which, again, you didn't include) is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` and `flatMap` apply to Arrays. Your `InvoiceItems` is an object.

```
export type InvoiceItems = {
  [invoiceItemId: string]: InvoiceItemData;
};
```

Even if you were to iterate across it with `for ... in` or [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), bear in mind that your use of the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) will cause it to be possibly `undefined`: you'll need to check for that yourself.